# Unable to debug Xamarin iOS App from Visual Studio 2015 after upgrade

Tags: xamarin.ios

I was able to debug my Xamarin cross-platform app on iOS as well as Android using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows.  Recently, I installed Xamarin updates on Windows as well as Mac.  After the upgrade, I am no longer able to debug portable library from iOS app.  Breakpoint hits MainActivity.cs but later it doesn't stop at other breakpoints in portable library.

However, if I open the same project in Xamarin Studio on Mac, I can debug iOS and Android app.

Anybody has any idea about the possible solution for the issue?

Windows:

- Visual Studio 2015
- Xamarin 4.5.0.486
- Xamarin.Android 7.3.1.2
- Xamarin.iOS 10.10.0.37

Mac:

- Xamarin Studio Enterprise 6.3
- Xamarin.Mac 3.4.0.36
- Xamarin.Android 7.3.1.2
- Xamarin.iOS 10.10.0.36
- XCode 8.3.3
- iOS 10.3